# discord line color off

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How to remove the strip to the left of the insert so that it turns out, as in screenshot #1, removing `setColor` does not help. Is it an embed at all?

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF8lW.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW6yq.png

Comment: The first embed has the color set the same as the embed background color, giving the illusion that a color has not been set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove it. You have to set the color to "#2F3136" (3092790) which is the embed background color.